# When I send a message to the telegram bot it does not send me a message back

Tags: python, flask, request, bots, telegram

I don't think there is an error in my code. When a request comes to the server, it most likely returns 403 forbidden. (Because it returned this expression when I made a local get request.)How can I fix this?

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests 

app = Flask(__name__)

key  = "my token"

def sendMessage(chatid):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{key}/sendMessage"
    payload = {
        "text": "heyy MAL",
        "chat_id": chatid
        }
    
    resp = requests.get(url, params=payload)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST","GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        resp = request.get_json()
        msgtext = resp["message"]["text"]
        sendername = resp["message"]["from"]["first_name"]
        chatid = resp["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        sendMessage(chatid)
    return "Done"
    
@app.route("/setwebhook/", methods=["GET"])
def setwebhook():
    url = "my url"
    s = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{key}/setWebhook?url={url}")
    if s.status_code == 200:
        return "Webhook set successfully"
    else:
        return "Webhook set failed"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I disabled mod security via cpanel but it didn't work.